# KeyError at 'body' when i send a request with fecth. Django and ReactJs project

Tags: reactjs, json, django, api

i´m doing a project with django (django rest framework) as backend and React js as Front for some reason the 'body' isn´t send  to the backend.

here the django view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def crearTarea(request):
    data = request.data
    print(data['body'])
    tarea = Tarea.objects.create(
        body=data['body']
    )
    serializer = TareaSerializer(tarea, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

the request in react with fetch:

```
let crear = () =>{
        let tarea_json = {
            "titulo": document.getElementById("titulo").value ,
            "descripcion": tarea.descripcion,
            "tiempo_tarea": 1,
            "fk_idUsuario": 1
        }

        fetch('/api/tareas/create', {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(tarea_json),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
    }
```

the model:

```
class Tarea(models.Model):

    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    tiempo_tarea = models.ForeignKey(Tiempo_tarea, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    fk_idUsuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["created"]
        db_table = "Tarea"
        verbose_name_plural = "Tareas"
        verbose_name = "Tarea"

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.titulo
```

and the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSSpk.png)

i´m traying to create a new instance with the method POST and fecth but it doesn´t run.

I would be grateful if you could help me

Comment: to debug your program try first to `print(data)` and looks what you got .it seems like `body` is not in `data.keys()`.

Comment: Thanks man,  yes the json isn´t in data.body, because de json is in the data atribute.